# readTextAsync WinJS cannot work

Tags: visual-studio, winjs

I need to read content from file. I have global variable fileDate and I want to put content to this variable, but when I call load method, the variable is undefined.

```
    var filename = "dataFile.txt";
    var fileDate;

WinJS.UI.Pages.define("index.html", {
        ready: function (element, options) {
            loadDate();
            console.log("main" + fileDate);
            this.fillYearSelect();
        },

  function loadDate() {
        return localFolder.getFileAsync(filename).then(function (file) {
            return Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(file).then(function (fileContent) {
                fileDate = fileContent;
                console.log("fileContent " + fileContent);
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("Błąd odczytu");
            });
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("Nie znaleziono pliku");
        });
    }
```

Sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that javascript is asynchronous, when you call `console.log("main" + fileDate)`, the method `loadDate()` is not finished, and that is why your fileDate is not defined (yet).

You could use promises to achieve this.

Here is an example based on your code :

```
var filename = "dataFile.txt";
var fileDate;

var applicationData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;
var localFolder = applicationData.localFolder;

function loadDate() {
    return new Promise(function (onComplete, onError) {
        localFolder.getFileAsync(filename).then(function (file) {

            Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(file).then(function (fileContent) {
                fileDate = fileContent;
                console.log("fileContent " + fileContent);

                onComplete(fileDate);
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("Error on readTextAsync");
                onError(error);
            });
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("Error on getFileAsync");
            onError(error);
        });
    });
}
```

Now `loadDate()`returns a promise, you can now use `.then()` method to do things when `loadDate()` is finished.

```
loadDate().then(function (fileDate) {
        console.log("Content : " + fileDate);
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```